# Is it safe to have various Perl installations on one machine share a cpan_home?

Tags: perl, cpan

I have a dated system perl 5.8.8 on a Linux machine and installed a 5.12.4 from ActiveState. Both perl's `cpan_home` is `~root/.cpan`. I was about to change the new perl's `cpan_home`, but then I realized I didn't *know* whether I really have to do this or whether it would just result in multiple copies of modules being downloaded to different directories when in fact they could be shared.

So can they? Is it safe? With regard to compiling? Or do I have to go for separate `cpan_home` directories?

Note that I tried [perlbrew](http://perlbrew.pl/) first but it failed with `Can't load '../lib/auto/IO/IO.so' for module IO: ../lib/auto/IO/IO.so: wrong ELF class: ELFCLASS64 at ../lib/XSLoader.pm line 70.` So instead of pursueing the issue I went for ActivePerl, which installs easily.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I have a dozen builds of Perl on my system, and they all use `~/.cpan`. I have never had a problems, but I cannot say that it is safe. It depends on the settings therein. Specifically,

- `build_dir_reuse` should (probably) be zero.
- `makepl_arg` shouldn't contain `INSTALL_BASE`.
- `mbuildpl_arg` shouldn't contain `--install_base`.

"Install base" overrides where the modules are installed. If you start installing the modules for all your builds in one location, you will have problems due to incompatibilities between versions, releases and builds of Perl.

If you want to share `.cpan` and have a local install directory, you can probably get away with using `PREFIX=/home/username/perl5 LIB=/home/username/perl5/lib` instead of `INSTALL_BASE=/home/username/perl5`. It uses a smarter directory structure.

By the way, local::lib causes "install base" to be used, so you'll run into problems if you use local::lib with multiple installs of Perl.

Comment: Thanks, ikegami. `build_dir_reuse` does sound like it has the potential to confuse things. Not sure I'm following you wrt `INSTALL_BASE`, though. Those settings reside in `CPAN/Config.pm`, and even with separate `.cpan` but mistakenly identical setting you could clobber one perl's modules with another one's modules. On the other hand, a shared `.cpan` where each perl has its own reasonable `INSTALL_BASE` sounds okay, no? But you have more rep than me so you likely know better ... :)

Comment: They're in `~/.cpan/CPAN/MyConfig.pm`.

Comment: How can the config file be *shared* by different builds yet have different settings for different builds?

Comment: I don't have the `~/.cpan/CPAN/MyConfig.pm` you're referring to. When I said `CPAN/Config.pm`, I was referring to the `/usr/lib/perl5/5.10/CPAN/Config.pm` (or whatever the path of the perl in question). Each `CPAN/Config.pm` has the appropriate settings for that perl but they might all share one `~/.cpan` directory; at least I thought they might, and you said they did on your system.

Comment: @Lumi, I don't have a `CPAN::Config` in any of my installs on this machine (with Debian and numerous perlbrew builds). It must be something your distro added. Your perlbrew installs definitely won't come with one, and `cpan` will create `~/.cpan/CPAN/MyConfig.pm` the first time its run unless you make sure to create a `CPAN/Config.pm` first. If you're going to do that, you might as well have them each use a different directory.

Comment: I think it might be created when you do `o conf commit` in the cpan shell to save your settings. The top of the file has the following comment: *This is CPAN.pm's systemwide configuration file. This file provides defaults for users, and the values can be changed in a per-user configuration file. The user-config file is being looked for as /home/MiLu/.cpan/CPAN/MyConfig.pm.* So both files we're talking about may or may not be there. Thanks for your help.

Comment: One of the two will ALWAYS be there when `cpan` is running. Again, `~/.cpan/CPAN/MyConfig.pm` is created when `cpan` is started if you don't have a `CPAN/Config.pm`. And unless you create it yourself (or have someone create it for you, as the case for your AP build, BUT WON'T NECESSARILY BE THE CASE FOR ANY OTHER BUILDS), you don't have a `CPAN/Config.pm`. Of course `o conf commit` will also create it.